# Shell restarting rather than running code

Tags: python, class

Trying to draw a straight line using

```
import turtle

def draw_line():
window =turtle.Screen()
window.bgcolor("blue")

animal=turtle.Turtle ()
animal.forward(100)

window.exitonclick()

draw_line()
```

but the shell keeps restarting and doesn't run the code.
Help!

Comment: Indent the code. Not able to understand what is under def draw_sqaure?

Comment: "Shell"? What shell?

Comment: my apologies. I meant a line

Comment: @yusssk, there's still no indentation, so we don't know when the function definition finishes (and neither would the Python interpreter, if we tried to copy-and-paste it).

Comment: @yusssk, ...when you say "shell keeps restarting", what does that actually mean? Nothing in this code involves a literal copy of `/bin/sh`, which is the usual meaning of "shell" -- do you mean the window flickers? Do you mean the Python interpreter exits? If it exits, does it write anything to stderr? If so, what?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy i mean the stack viewer, it displays {================ RESTART: /Users/Documents/line.py ================}

Comment: stack viewer?  Are you running this through some form of GUI?  There are sometimes issues mixing Tk with a GUI, try running it from the command-line.

Comment: Please make a habit of always including the *exact* output (including your `RESTART: ` message and anything else alongside it) in your question. If there's a syntax error or import error given, for instance, that's what we need to have a definitive answer to your question.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to run your code as follows:

```
import turtle

def draw_line():
    window = turtle.Screen()
    window.bgcolor('blue')
    animal = turtle.Turtle()
    animal.forward(100)
    window.exitonclick()

draw_line()
```

And I can successfully run it.

I saved the above code in a file called `turtle_test.py` and ran it on the command line like this:

```
python turtle_test.py
```

For me that opens a new window with the expected output and it closes on click.

I tried it with both Python 2.6 and Python 3.5. Neither version had a problem with this script. One thing I have to mention though is that the window created by this script did not get focus automatically. I had to find it by Alt-Tab'ing, maybe that's your problem as well?

Also sorry for answering without a definitive answer, but it seems I need 'points' to be able to post a comment..

Comment: If the OP's indentation truly was what they put in their question, this arguably *is* a legitimate answer. :)

Comment: Damn. It returns >>> 
================ RESTART: /Users//Documents/line.py ================
>>> every time i try to run it. What might be the cause?

Comment: Well, like said in the comments on your answer: it seems like you're running your code in some kind of GUI. What are you using, and did you try to run this on the command line?

Comment: @jasper not running code in any GUI, however i don't understand what a command line is, this is my second day of programming in python. I am running the code in IDLE